# Android softkeyboard under the EditText - Setting the softkeyboard position

Tags: android

I have list of order product & that list contain quantity in `editText` . I want to display softkeyboard under the editText.That keyboard need to contain 0-9 , . , enter key.

First question is How we can get the EditText  from the list for particular row?
second is : How to display softkeyboard under the particular row?

that means softkeyboard should display under the edittext box. not bottom screen .

I tried like this :

```
  EditText yourEditText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditText);
  InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
  imm.showSoftInput(yourEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

But here I have confused how to get the particular row's editText (yourEditText)?

That is multicolumn listview.

Answer (score 0):

I'm honestly not sure what your first question means, however if you wish to change the input keyboard for a particular `EditText` you can do so in the XML by putting `android:numeric="decimal"` for example.

[Further documentation about input types](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/on-screen-inputs.html)